# When I try to work with pytube, raising error, but i downloaded this module. (Python, Pytube)

Tags: python, pytube

```
import pytube

url = 'https://youtu.be/xpVfcZ0ZcFM'

youtube = pytube.YouTube(url)
video = youtube.streams.first()
video.download("C:\Lego")``
```

the error:

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Programming/Hillel/CW/CW24/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'
```

Comment: did you install it with `pip install pytube`? If yes - do you have more than one python installation?

Answer (score 0):

To use a module it needs to be available.
The most likely scenario is that you haven't installed `pytube`

Try running:

```
pip install pytube
```

If that doesn't work consider reading through the import [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) briefly. The pip [documentation](https://github.com/pypa/pip) might also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your python or pip is not on PATH or you did not install it. Install it using

```
pip install pytube
```

OR

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git
```

If you have git installed in windows.